# Is there a way to access filesystem from a HTML5 App in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml, javascript

I'm trying to adapt a html5 app written originnally for Firefox OS to Ubuntu Touch. There are various issues, like file system access, contacts access, notifications and others. I want to know if there is a javascript API to access system resources. If the only way is using QML I would ask:"Is there a way to bind a html5 app to QML in order to access system resources listed above?"

Thanks